# Is there a good general purpose options class for c++?

Tags: c++

Each time I write another one of my small c++ toy programs, I come across the need for a small, easy-to-use options/parameter class. Here is what it should be able to do:

- accept at least ints, doubles, string parameters
- easy way to add new options
- portable, small and fast
- free
- read options from a file and/or command line
- upper and lower bounds for parameters
- and all the other neat useful things I am not thinking of right now

What I want to do is pass a pointer to this class to the builder and all of my strategy objects, so they can read the parameters of the algorithm I am running (e.g. which algorithm, maximum number of iterations etc.)

Can someone point me to an implementation that achieves at least some of these things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Boost Program-Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/program_options.html) is pretty slick.  I think it does all the things on your list, apart from maybe bounds validation.  But even then, you can provide custom validators pretty easily.

**Update:** As @stefan rightly points out in a comment, this also fails on "small"!  It adds quite a significant chunk to your binary if you statically link it in.

Comment: I wont down vote you but "portable, *small and fast*" would rule out boost.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was hoping for - I searched through boost earlier, but I seem to have overlooked it ...

Comment: @stefan: Yes, I definitely missed "small" out of the list.  But I'm not sure "fast" is really going to be an issue with this sort of task.  Regarding "portable", do you know of any particular issues with this library?  (I would be interested if there are any, because I use it somewhat frequently.)

Comment: Chalesworth well, every local hack i've seen has been far faster than boost in anything. Not saying it will be needed here, but the author requested it. The only thing I know that is even remotely public and has optimized meta programming is fusion by jukka liimatta at http://liimatta.org/ but it targets a completely difference audience, but for meta programming it (when i checked it out) did put most TL's into the corner.

Comment: +1 `boost::po` make it easy to create the scaffolding needed to obtain options from a variety of sources in your program. I somewhat argue against the "small and fast" detractors since both are a relative measurement.  Using the right tool for the job is more important in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider storing your configuration in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format. While reading JSON from the command-line is slightly awkward, it's still perfectly doable and even reasonably legible. Other than that you get a whole lot of flexibility, including nested configuration options, facilities for deserializing complicated data types etc.

There are numerous libraries for de-serializing JSON into C++, see e.g. [this discussion and comparison](https://blog.thousandeyes.com/efficiency-comparison-c-json-libraries/) of a few of them. Some are small, many are fast (although you don't actually need them to be fast - configuration data is very small), most are very portable. A long list and some benchmark results (although not a feature comparison) can be found [here](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark); some of these libraries might actually be geared towards use for reading configuration options, although that's just a wild guess.